# A question about the correct way to plot a time series data

Tags: r, plot, time-series

**Description of data**

I have 3 datasets stored in data frames and called: `df1, df2 and df3`. Each data set measures something different *at the same time* but using the same variables: `V1, ..., V7`.

For this work, I can say that each data set represents a multivariate time series since all variables are measuring the samething for each data set at many times: `1, ...,.6,... n`. Additionally, we can assume that all data sets represent 3 multivariate time series as there are three data frames.

**The shape of data:**

```
head(df1)
   Time   V1   V2         V3         V4          V5         V6         V7
X1 10:00  0 0.1182197 0.09057301 0.08089888 0.003350084 0.00000000 0.00000000
X2 10:01  0 0.1276078 0.09242144 0.01348315 0.060301508 0.02245599 0.02298152
X3 10:02  0 0.1369958 0.12569316 0.03595506 0.159128978 0.04491198 0.04596305
X4 10:03  0 0.1029207 0.10166359 0.08089888 0.201005025 0.06736798 0.06894457
X5 10:04  0 0.1585535 0.14510166 0.08089888 0.112227806 0.08982397 0.09192609
X6 10:05  0 0.1488178 0.00000000 0.07415730 0.212730318 0.11227996 0.11490761
                                .
                                .
                                .


#df2 and df3 have the same shpae, time and dimensions exactly as df1 but with different values.
```

I have two questions:

**1.** When plotting data of `df1` only, which is more correct to represent this time series:

**1.1** To consider the whole data frame as a time series, so to do

```
library(mvtsplot) 
mvtsplot(df1)
```

**1.2** or to consider each row as a time series and to plot `n` time series

```
#considering that there are 10 rows in df1
ts.plot(X1,..,X10)
```

**2.** Can I plot the three multivariate time series in the same plot so to have a figure contains the 3 multivariate time series.

**EDIT:** Following to the comment of [rajah9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509840/rajah9), The data of `df1` represent a certain amount of gas measured by `7 sensors (variables V1, ..., V7 )` each minute. The other two `df2, df3` represent another types of gases measured using the same sensors at the same time but in different experiments. Each data frame seems like a multivariate time series and I don't have a dependent variable. Are my thoughts correct?

Any answer or link to a similar question would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is a time series, which vector has the time? They all look like dependent y variables, and you'll need the independent time variable as well.

Comment: thanks for posting the time series. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195398/plot-time-series-in-r-ggplot-using-multiple-groups or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580526/difficulty-plotting-time-series-in-r

Comment: @rajah9 Thanks a lot for the links. It seems that questions in your links asking to plot many univariate time series in the same plot. My question is different. I want to know what is the correct way to plot a multivariate time series. Then, how to plot many multivariate time series in the same plot? Additionally, why don't you think that using `mvtsplot()` could be more correct for the questions asked in your attached links?

Answer (score 0):

### Q1

It looks like for Q1.1 that `mvtsplot` is the way to go, as it was designed for multivariate time series.

You can see the [mvtsplot documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/mvtsplot/man/mvtsplot.html).

### Q2

Assuming that the three plots have close to the same data, you could for Q2 plot them all on the same graph, but I think it would be quite difficult to distinguish.

Do the three dataframes on one graph tell a different story? Or would the reader's eye be naturally drawn to an anomaly in, say, df3?

Try plotting df1, df2, and df3 separately first.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. The 3 data frames are not that close to each other since they are measuring different readings, although the measure are take at the same time, so presenting the 3 curves in the same plot would be great. Unfortunately, all ways I tried are designed to plot many univariate( NOT multivariate) ts in the same plot. In fact, I don't know how to calibrate mvtsplot() to add the three mv ts in the same plot! Do you have any advices please?